# Client side React-Router demo: invariant violation

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router

I'm following the React-Router [guide](https://github.com/rackt/react-router/blob/master/docs/guides/basics/RouteConfiguration.md)
But getting this error in the browser console:

```
14:14:28.840 Error: Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected
a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite 
components) but got: undefined.1 react.js:18307:15
```

I don't know what's wrong - the React-Router classes are imported and should be valid React Classes. The one difference is I'm loading the classes-client side rather than server-side.

Here is the code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/0.14.0/react-dom.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-router/0.13.4/ReactRouter.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/babel-core/5.6.15/browser.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div id="content"></div>
    <script type="text/babel">
    var Route = window.ReactRouter.Route;
    var Router = window.ReactRouter.Router;
    var Link  = window.ReactRouter.Link;
    var DefaultRoute = window.ReactRouter.DefaultRoute;
    var RouteHandler = window.ReactRouter.RouteHandler;
    var IndexRoute = window.ReactRouter.IndexRoute;

    const App = React.createClass({
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h1>App</h1>
            <ul>
              <li><Link to="/about">About</Link></li>
              <li><Link to="/inbox">Inbox</Link></li>
            </ul>
            {this.props.children}
          </div>
        )
      }
    })

    const About = React.createClass({
      render() {
        return <h3>About</h3>
      }
    })

    const Inbox = React.createClass({
      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <h2>Inbox</h2>
            {this.props.children || "Welcome to your Inbox"}
          </div>
        )
      }
    })

    const Message = React.createClass({
      render() {
        return <h3>Message {this.props.params.id}</h3>
      }
    })
    ReactDOM.render((
      <Router>
        <Route path="/" component={App}>
          <Route path="about" component={About} />
          <Route path="inbox" component={Inbox}>
            <Route path="messages/:id" component={Message} />
          </Route>
        </Route>
      </Router>
    ), document.getElementById('content'));
    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: why are you mixing es6 and es5 syntax?

Comment: browser.js didn't recognize my `import` calls ("require is undefined") so I'm using the syntax suggested on the react-router [introduction](https://github.com/rackt/react-router#umd)

Comment: why are you using `const App = React.createClass` instead of `class App extends React.Component` ? that is the preferred way to create a class and you should follow their instructions. also I dont see any import calls so edit your question with the relevant information

Comment: class extends is not the syntax shown in the official react [tutorial](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/tutorial.html). I've already explained why I'm NOT using `import` and I've linked to the documentation I'm following.

Comment: if you are using es6 syntax... then you should [follow their docs for es6](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/reusable-components.html) I know about react-router.. ive even created issues / pull requests for it.. but es6 with react should use the react preferred syntax

Comment: Switching to the ES6 `class extends` returns the same error as before. If you have some advice that would help me solve this problem, I'd love to hear it.

Comment: I can't tell whats going on because I dont see any require statements or anything and I don't know where reactrouter is getting pulled in.. but you should try making sure you have reactrouter on the window aka `console.log(window.ReactRouter)` if that is there then you need to post more relevant data in the question around where you are setting ReactRouter on the window and stuff

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Found the issue: I was using the old (v0.13x) version of react-router with the 1.0.0 syntax. You can get the new version on [CDNJS](https://cdnjs.com/libraries/react-router/1.0.0-rc1) or change the version select box to get an older version.

Answer (score 0):

I've had this also occur when customizing/using the [React Redux Starter Kit](https://github.com/davezuko/react-redux-starter-kit).

In my case, I was using the ES6/2015 module `import` syntax in a faulty way (importing a *named* `export` when I actually needed the *default* `export`).

When declaring a component, e.g.

```
export default class SomeComponent extends React.Component {   
  render() {
    return (
      // ...
    );   
  } 
}

SomeComponent.propTypes = {
  // ...
};
```

Using `import { SomeComponent } from '<...>/SomeComponent'` **instead** of
`import SomeComponent from [...]` would yield the same error.

My IDE warned me but I thought that was just some linting error.

Even though the Redux DevTools would pick up on an `undefined` element when not `import`ing at all (e.g. just using `<SomeComponent>`), I would get this same error message, although it's unrelated to `react-router`.

Here are the DevTools errors for reference purposes:

`Warning: React.createElement: type should not be null, undefined, boolean, or number. It should be a string (for DOM elements) or a ReactClass (for composite components). Check the render method of <...>`

`Uncaught Invariant Violation: Element type is invalid: expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. Check the render method of <...>`